# Change stacking order ggplot - geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I've been having trouble plotting this using `geom_bar`. I would like a plot just like this (see below), but with the stacking order reversed (light colour is at the top of the bold colour). 
**I want the little bars to move to the top of the graph**

Here is the image and below is the plot I get.

[image]

And here is my data frame:

```
> gluft
      sex mito nac tissue variable       value        se      int
2  female   WT   0 thorax     GSHr  8056.17054 1591.0030  WT.GSHr
4  female   WT   1 thorax     GSHr  7419.13560 1068.4371  WT.GSHr
6  female   WT  10 thorax     GSHr  7719.67792  133.9016  WT.GSHr
8  female  COX   0 thorax     GSHr 17929.34775  790.0533 COX.GSHr
10 female  COX   1 thorax     GSHr 16382.40832  277.0276 COX.GSHr
12 female  COX  10 thorax     GSHr 17087.65114 4735.9644 COX.GSHr
14 female  BAR   0 thorax     GSHr 15354.80693 3350.8182 BAR.GSHr
16 female  BAR   1 thorax     GSHr 16398.20256 2484.8879 BAR.GSHr
18 female  BAR  10 thorax     GSHr 15129.48573  676.4322 BAR.GSHr
20 female   WT   0 thorax     diff    80.56171 1606.9130  WT.diff
22 female   WT   1 thorax     diff    74.19136 1079.1214  WT.diff
24 female   WT  10 thorax     diff    77.19678  135.2406  WT.diff
26 female  COX   0 thorax     diff   179.29348  797.9538 COX.diff
28 female  COX   1 thorax     diff   163.82408  279.7979 COX.diff
30 female  COX  10 thorax     diff   170.87651 4783.3241 COX.diff
32 female  BAR   0 thorax     diff   129.70685 3368.7446 BAR.diff
34 female  BAR   1 thorax     diff   163.98203 2509.7368 BAR.diff
36 female  BAR  10 thorax     diff   983.08450 1173.1470 BAR.diff
```

The first thing I do is change the factor levels:

```
gluft$nac <- factor(gluft$nac)    
gluft$int <- factor(gluft$int, levels = c("WT.GSHr","COX.GSHr","BAR.GSHr", "WT.diff","COX.diff","BAR.diff"))
```

Then I plot the data:

```
ggplot(data=gluft, aes(x=nac, y=value, group=mito))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=int),
           stat = "identity",
           position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(
       breaks=c("WT.GSHr","COX.GSHr","BAR.GSHr","WT.diff","COX.diff","BAR.diff"),
        values=c("blue4", "green4","red2","lightblue","lightgreen","pink"))
```

Now I've tried changing the factor levels back and forth, and it does nothing.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So just to clarify, I dont want to swap the colours, but rather get the little bars to move to the top of the graph

Answer (score 0):

I think this may do what you need. I just changed the order of the colors in

```
values(...)
```

Now your image should have the light colors on top and the bold colors at the bottom. Here is the full code.

```
ggplot(data=gluft, aes(x=nac, y=value, group=mito))+
geom_bar(aes(fill=int),
       stat = "identity",
       position=position_dodge())+
scale_fill_manual(
   breaks=c("WT.GSHr","COX.GSHr","BAR.GSHr","WT.diff","COX.diff","BAR.diff"),
    values=c("lightblue","lightgreen","pink","blue4", "green4","red2"))
```

Cheers ;-)

Ok, now I see what you were asking for. I did find a solution without using ggplot2, and this is probably not the most elegant, but it does the trick. I first reduced the dataset to include only the columns that are needed. Then used the function spread() from the tidyr package to make the df from long format to wide. Then I built a stacked barplot using the simple plotting commands.

```
library(tidyr)

gluft1 <- gluft[,c("int", "value", "nac")]
data_wide <- spread(gluft1, nac, value)

barplot(as.matrix(data_wide[1:3,2:4]) + as.matrix(data_wide[4:6,2:4]), beside = T, col = c("yellow","lightgreen","pink"))
barplot(as.matrix(data_wide[1:3,2:4]), beside = T, col = c("blue4", "green4","red2"), add = T)
```

The result should be the following graph:

[image]

You can then add your legend.
Hopefully this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, but I might not have been exactly clear on what I wanted. I want the small bit at the bottom to be physically at the top (not a colour swap). Would you have some insights?

Comment: Hi fdros, I edited my previous answer and I found an alternative. Hopefully that works for you. Cheers.